# Kendo MVC Grid - get cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am migrating my application form MVC Extension to the Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC. Changed the grid to:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<vw_Client_info>)ViewBag.Clients)
 .Name("Clients")
 .Columns(columns =>
     {
      columns.Bound(c => c.ClientID).Width(30).Title("Client ID").Hidden();
      columns.Bound(c => c.FullName).Width(130);
     })
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
  .Ajax()
  .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ClientID))
  .Read(read => read.Action("AllClientsSelection", "Visit")))
  .Selectable()
  .Events(events =>
    {  events.Change("onRowSelected"); })
 .RowAction(row => row.Selected = row.DataItem.ClientID.Equals(ViewData["id"]))
                )
```

To get the cell value, I used before :

```
function onRowSelected(e) {
        var detailGrid = $('#Visit').data('tGrid');
        id = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML;
        fullname = e.row.cells[1].innerHTML;
        $('#ClientFullName').text(fullname);
          detailGrid.rebind();
    }
```

This works with Telerik MVC Extensions , but not with the new version, I get this error:

```
Unable to get property 'cells' of undefined or null reference.
```

I tried to use:

```
 function onRowSelected(e) {
        var detailGrid = $('#Visit').data('kendoGrid');
        var id = e.row.ClientID;
        var fullname = e.row.FullName;
        $('#ClientFullName').text(fullname);
          detailGrid.rebind();
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to get property 'ClientID' of undefined or null reference
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

```
 var grid = $("#Clients").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        id = selectedItem.ClientID;
        fullname = selectedItem.FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the value of 'row' in:

```
var id = e.row.ClientID;
```

is null. So you might want to check if row is null before setting ClientID or cells[0] or cells[1] to the variables. So perhaps:

```
var id = null;
if(e.row != null)
   id = e.row.ClientId
```

However, I think you might need to debug and find out if you're getting any 'row' count at all, though. Because if there is no 'row' then there is no 'row.ClientId' .